# Create View with Multiple Models and Forms with Validation - MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I create a view that has multiple models that need validation and also has multiple forms to submit all within the same view?

*I have the solution below. As I was typing it up I was able to figure it out, so hopefully it will help someone else. If others have a better approach or comments, please feel free to post!*

Answer (score 0):

I have a view that contains a ViewModel, which combines 2 models. Here is the ViewModel, along with the other classes:

```
public class PlayerFormViewModel
{
    public PlayerFormEnglish PlayerFormEnglish { get; set; }
    public PlayerFormSpanish PlayerFormSpanish { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerFormEnglish : PlayerFormInformation { }

public class PlayerFormSpanish : PlayerFormInformation { }

public class PlayerFormInformation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is a required field.")]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    // Used as a dropdown in the view
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Gender{ get; set; }
}
```

My main view contains the ViewModel and 2 forms:

```
@model Namespace.Models.PlayerFormViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PlayerTest", "Profile"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <h3>English</h3>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PlayerFormEnglish.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PlayerFormEnglish.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PlayerFormEnglish.FirstName)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PlayerFormEnglish.Gender)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlayerFormEnglish.Gender, new SelectList(Model.PlayerFormEnglish.Gender, "Value", "Text"))

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="ButtonType" value="SaveEnglishForm">Save</button>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("PlayerTest", "Profile"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <h3>Spanish</h3>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PlayerFormSpanish.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PlayerFormSpanish.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PlayerFormSpanish.FirstName)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PlayerFormSpanish.Gender)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlayerFormSpanish.Gender, new SelectList(Model.PlayerFormEnglish.Gender, "Value", "Text"))

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="ButtonType" value="SaveSpanishForm">Save</button>
}
```

When the page first loads, I pre-populate the fields like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PlayerTest()
{
    PlayerFormViewModel model = new PlayerFormViewModel();
    model.PlayerFormEnglish = new PlayerFormEnglish();
    model.PlayerFormSpanish = new PlayerFormSpanish();
    model.PlayerFormEnglish.FirstName = "Brad";

    List<SomeObject> genderList = GetDataForDropdown();

    model.PlayerFormEnglish.Gender = ConvertData(genderList);
    model.PlayerFormSpanish.Gender = ConvertData(genderList);
    return View(model);
}
```

Finally, I validate and update the saved form when a user clicks the save button:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult PlayerTest(PlayerFormViewModel model, string ButtonType)
{
    if (ButtonType.Equals("SaveEnglishForm"))
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SuccessfulSave", "Profile");
        }
        model.PlayerFormSpanish = new PlayerFormSpanish();
    }
    else
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SuccessfulSave", "Profile");
        }
        model.PlayerFormEnglish = new PlayerFormEnglish();
    }

    // I can repopulate the fields here just as before
    model.PlayerFormEnglish.FirstName = "Brad";

    List<SomeObject> genderList = GetDataForDropdown();

    model.PlayerFormEnglish.Gender = ConvertData(genderList);
    model.PlayerFormSpanish.Gender = ConvertData(genderList);

    // Return model which will mark the required fields in the UI
    return View(model);
}
```

Hope this helps!